# VarArrayLowBound() fails with index error on multi-dimension Variant array

Tags: c++, c++builder

There is a procedure in C++Builder that has a `Variant& Values` parameter.

It is in a format where `Values[n1][n2]` is used, so I expected the following to work, but there is a runtime error about an invalid index when trying to use `VarArrayLowBound(Values, 2)`.

```
for (int i=VarArrayLowBound(Values, 1); i<=VarArrayHighBound(Values, 1); i++) {
    for (int j=VarArrayLowBound(Values, 2); j<=VarArrayHighBound(Values, 2);j++) {
```

Instead, I can get it working by using this:

```
Variant v=Values.GetElement(n1);
String s=VarToStr(v.GetElement(n2));
```

Likewise, if I try `Values.GetElement(n1, n2);` that fails with the invalid index error as well.

What is the difference?

The docs suggest that `VarArrayLowBound(Values, 2);` would get the value for the second dimension.

It would be easier to use `Values[n1][n2]`, but they protected the `[]` operator so it can't be used.

Comment: When looping over any kind of indexable container, the condition `<=` is almost *never* right. Remember that in C++ indexes are zero-based, which means a container of `N` elements will have indexes from `0` to `N - 1` (inclusive). With the condition `<=` you will include the index `N`  which will then be out of bounds. Of course, with C++Builder and its Delphi-based libraries things might be different.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude in this case, `<=` is fine to use as the code is looping though `Low` to `High` (inclusive). What you say is true if it were looping through `Low` to `Length` (non-inclusive) instead. Also, Variant arrays are not required to be 0-indexed (though they typically are), hence the need to retrieve the actual `Low` index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Values` is not a *multi-dimensional* array, which is why trying to access its 2nd dimension fails.

`Values` is actually a *single-dimensional* array, where each element is a separate *single-dimensional* array.

You can verify this by using [`VarArrayDimCount()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Variants.VarArrayDimCount) or [`Variant::ArrayDimCount()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Variant.ArrayDimCount) to check how many dimensions each `Variant` has.

As such, your outer loop needs to access each array element of the 1st dimension only, thus allowing the inner loop to access the elements of that array's 1st dimension, eg:

```cpp
for (int i = VarArrayLowBound(Values, 1), high1 = VarArrayHighBound(Values, 1); i <= high1; ++i) {
    Variant elem1 = VarArrayGet(Values, OPENARRAY(int, (i)) ); // or: VarArrayGet(Values, &i, 0)
    for (int j = VarArrayLowBound(elem1, 1), high2 = VarArrayHighBound(elem1, 1); j <= high2; ++j) {
        Variant elem2 = VarArrayGet(elem1, OPENARRAY(int, (j)) ); // or: VarArrayGet(elem1, &j, 0)
        // use elem2 as needed...
        String s = VarToStr(elem2);
        ...
    }
}
```

Alternatively, a slightly cleaner approach would be to use the member methods of the `Variant` class instead of the standalone global functions, eg:

```cpp
for (int i = Values.ArrayLowBound(), high1 = Values.ArrayHighBound(); i <= high1; ++i) {
    Variant elem1 = Values.GetElement(i);
    for (int j = elem1.ArrayLowBound(), high2 = elem1.ArrayHighBound(); j <= high2; ++j) {
        Variant elem2 = elem1.GetElement(j);
        // use elem2 as needed...
        String s = elem2;
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <Variant.h>

void ExampleFunction()
{
    Variant values = VarArrayCreate(VarArrayDefault, TVarType::varDouble, System::VarArrayOf(
        System::VarArrayOf(1.0, 2.0, 3.0),
        System::VarArrayOf(4.0, 5.0, 6.0),
        System::VarArrayOf(7.0, 8.0, 9.0)
    ));

    int dimension = 2; // Second dimension

    int lowerBound = VarArrayLowBound(values, dimension);

    ShowMessage("Lower bound of dimension " + IntToStr(dimension) + ": " + IntToStr(lowerBound));
}
```

Comment: Please take some time to read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). What is the problem with the OP's code? this code doing? Why does it solve the problem the OP have? And of course spend at least *some* time to make sure the answer and its code is properly formatted.

Comment: This does not even attempt to answer the OP's question. It needs to be deleted

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).